# Image to 2d array in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I was wondering how to convert an image(PNG) to a 2D array of hex colors in Javascript on an HTML5 canvas. Via the context.getImageData() function.  P.S. If the alpha is 0, then could you set the hex color to "0".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to a 32bit array of words, check for alpha zero by masking the alpha and checking if it is zero, then set hex as zero, else mask out the alpha and add the hex colour format with "#" at the start.

```
const d32 = new Uint32Array(ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height).data.buffer);
const hexArray = [];
var i = 0;
while(i < data32.length){
    const data = ((d32[i] & 0xFF) << 16) + (d32[i] & 0xFF00) + ((d32[i] & 0xFF0000) >> 16);  
    hexArray.push(
        d32[i++] & 0xFF000000 ?
        "#" + (data | 0x1000000).toString(16).substr(1) :
        "0"
    );
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that the 32-bit version is in "reverse" byte-order ABGR. Newer browsers (currently only FF) also [supports alpha in the #-notation](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/4ttszs4m/), ie. #RRGGBBAA.